# Firebase Analytics and GoogleIDFASupport pod, is it required?

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-analytics

I'm trying to clean up a pod installation on a current project that has been using Firebase analytics for the last year or so. I have noticed that it has collected user data such as age and gender, from what I understand this is done like so:

> The iOS Identifier for Advertisers (IDFA). Applies to app activity only. When you use the Firebase Analytics tracking code in an iOS app to collect the IDFA, Firebase Analytics generates an identifier based on the IDFA that includes demographic and interest information associated with users’ app activity

However does this require the `GoogleIDFASupport` pod to work? I was using this previously for Google Analytics and would like to remove it if it's not used by Firebase. Any pointers on this would be really appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The IDFA is used in Firebase analytics SDK when users allow ad tracking automatically. Besides Firebase Analytics' dependencies like FirebaseCore, FA doesn't need GoogleIDFASupport.

Comment: Do they have a method to get the IDFA as a value? Or is this hidden from us?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need `GoogleIDFASupport` only if you use it in your reports.

Comment: But there is nothing in the documents about it. Also this feature has to be enabled for GA trackers e.g.` tracker.allowIDFACollection = true`, again there is no option to do this for Firebase.

Comment: @Kex I'm struggling with the same question, have you found the answer to this? :)

Answer (score 0):

No, it looks like `GoogleIDFASupport` is only use with `GoogleAnalytics` which is being replaced with `FirebaseAnalytics`.  `FirebaseAnalytics` include IDFA capability by default.  If you won't want to collect IDFA use `pod ‘Firebase/AnalyticsWithoutAdIdSupport’`.

Source:
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ios/changelog
https://firebase.google.com/docs/ios/installation-methods#analytics-enabled